# How to switch workspace in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, workspace

I work upon an Android project on MacOS. Recently i had to create a copy of my project in another location. Say it was `Users/user/SVN/Applications/BarPoject/AndroidBarProject` and now it is `Users/user/Projects/AndroidBarProject`.

Now i'm trying to make Eclipse work with the project in new location. When launching Eclipse i browse to the new workspace then i click OK and then i'm presented with a popup alert which reads:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file /Users/user/Projects/AndroidBarProject/.metadata/.log
```

What i do next is i open Eclipse in the old workspace and click `File/Switch Workspace` but again i see exactly the same popup message. How do i fix it?

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: You start by following the instruction; Look at the log file. What does it say?

Comment: @ellak there's a lot of text in that file. it's really long

Comment: i would say it's incredibly huge

Comment: instead of switching the workspace did you try importing the project only in current ws? does that work?

Comment: Start looking at the end of the log file and see if you can spot anything interesting.

Comment: the log file says it's missing bin/jarlist.cache file. and really it was missing. but after i put that file into bin directory nothing has changed. it still complains there's no such a file in that directory

Comment: @newcomer no, i can't do that. it says "Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace"

Comment: ok that means your current ws folder already has the project. delete the project from current ws and try to import the project from other ws

Answer (score 0):

Open  Eclipse -> File -> Switch Work Space-> Other